Why Google Map polygon and camera is not working in jetpack compose?
I'm using Google Maps in my jetpack compose project by implementing the viewmodel. My code is partially working, it's adding the markers but it is not creating the polygon. And also I'm facing an issue with the camera position. When the map is loaded, it's not automatically zooming to the user's current location.
This is how my viewModel looks :
var positionLatLngList: SnapshotStateList<LatLng> = mutableStateListOf()
        private set

fun updatePositionMarkersList(position: LatLng){
        positionLatLngList.add(position)
    }

This is my composable file code :
val cameraPositionState = rememberCameraPositionState {
        position = CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(LatLng(1.35, 103.87), 10f)
    }

    var properties by remember {
        mutableStateOf(
            MapProperties(
                isMyLocationEnabled = true,
                mapType = MapType.SATELLITE
            )
        )
    }

    LaunchedEffect(viewModel.selectedMapType) {
        properties = properties.copy(mapType = viewModel.selectedMapType.mapType)
    }


  GoogleMap(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState,
            properties = properties,
            onMyLocationClick = {
                cameraPositionState.position =
                    CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(LatLng(it.latitude, it.longitude), 50f)
            },
            onMapClick = {
                viewModel.updatePositionMarkersList(it)
            }
        ) {
            viewModel.positionLatLngList.forEach {
                val markerState = rememberMarkerState()
                markerState.position = it
                Marker(
                    state = markerState,
                    draggable = true
                )
            }
            if (viewModel.positionLatLngList.isNotEmpty()) {
                Polygon(points = viewModel.positionLatLngList)
            }
        }


Can you provide a minimal reproducible example that demonstrates this issue? A sample GitHub repo would be nice. Also, did you make sure that you have set up the location permissions properly before fetching for the current location? I can only see in your code that you hardcoded the location instead of getting the location of the user.
